# Piping the output of a program to Preview.app

Tags: macos, unix, graphviz

I'm using an application (the `dot` program of the `graphviz` library) that generates a wide variety of file formats including PostScript and PDF. It can send the result to `stdout` or to a file. I'm currently sending it to a file and opening it with Preview.

Is there any way to pipe the output and have it be read by Preview, so that I'd don't have to generate a file and have it lying around? This is going to be used by a number of people who won't know the internal structure of the generating script and I don't want to clutter their folders or complicate their lives.

More generally, is there any way to take a program that sends its output to `stdout` and pass that output to an program that usually takes it's input from a file, without actually creating a file?

Comment: Save your document in `$TEMP` and then launch Preview using `open` - that way it will appear pretty seamless and the saved documents under `/tmp` will get cleaned up eventually.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$ your_program | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
```

Source: [View Terminal ‘man’ Pages In Preview / PDF (archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112042344/http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2012/01/view-terminal-man-pages-in-preview-pdf.html)

Comment: If you have graphviz installed `echo 'digraph { a -> b }' | dot -Tpng | open -f -a Preview` will open a pretty little directed graph!

Comment: It appears this functionality was removed in Ventura.

(also, the source link above is dead.)

Comment: @DaveL17 the source link is available throgh archive.org, I've updated my answer to reflect this. As for the functionality being removed, I'm afraid that's beyond me, in that I parted ways with Apple many years ago.

Comment: @ffact No worries. I was just adding a bit of insight for folks that might visit this QA in 2023.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

`f=$(mktemp -t test).txt; echo test > $f; open $f -a TextEdit # f=$TMPDIR/test.txt`